# Coredata Exception in iphone

Tags: iphone, core-data

I have created Core data app. It was working fine now it is giving exception

> Terminating app due to uncaught
>   exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   'Cannot create an
>   NSPersistentStoreCoordinator with a
>   nil model'

Whats the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can't find the generated .mom or .momd file. I would recommend deleting the instance of the app on the iPhone or iPhone simulator and re-running. You don't happen to have separate programs that rely on one Core Data model, do you?

Comment: Yeah, no problem. If this solved your issue, please mark it as the answer to your question (click on the empty check mark next to this post).

Comment: To the left of this post, right below the number 0 with the up and down arrows.